# jQuery clear input, textarea text on focus from dynamically added inputs

Tags: jquery, input, focus, dynamically-generated

I have jQuery script:

```
$("input:not(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset]'), textarea").each(function () {

var Input = $(this);
var default_value = Input.val();

$(Input).on("focus", function() {
    if(Input.val() == default_value) Input.val("");
}).on("blur", function() {
    if(Input.val().length == 0) Input.val(default_value);
});

});
```

Its working fine if inputs already on html, but how to make this work on dynamically added inputs?

First idea was to change:

```
$(Input).on("focus", function()
```

to

```
$(document).on("focus", Input, function()
```

but with no luck.

UPDATE

I think I found way to make it work properly on any inputs:

```
$(document).on("focus", "input:not(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset]'), textarea", function(e) {
if (e.target.value == e.target.defaultValue) {
    e.target.value = "";
}
}).on("blur", "input:not(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset]'), textarea", function(e) {
if (e.target.value == "") {
    e.target.value = e.target.defaultValue;
}
});
```

Comment: you need to put it after the creation of the new element... can you share how it is done

Comment: Click on "Add" link and when focus on new inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/r3ag5bL8/1/ Only first input removes text on focus.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h3arccea/3/ ?

Comment: Nop, only first input removes text on focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
$(".url_add").on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).prev(".elements").clone().insertBefore(this);
    e.preventDefault();
});
var default_value = $('input').val();
$(document).on("focus", 'input', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == default_value) $(this).val("");
}).on("blur", 'input', function () {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) $(this).val(default_value);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r3ag5bL8/3/)**

Comment: This way completely removes value from new inputs if you focus and when click away without entering any text.

Comment: You're right. That's odd, it looks like I left out a $(this) in the answer. Updated.